# How can I create a amazon sandbox account for developer purpose?

Tags: amazon-web-services

How can I create a amazon sandbox account for developer purpose using a dummy credit card number?

I searched lot in amazon website and Google but no information is available for developer. They ask for original credit card access.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### UPDATE

As seen in the comments to this post, Amazon no longer provides a staging / test environment.

---

How-to: **Amazon Marketplace Web Services (MWS) Staging Account**
We’ve been working on custom web application that integrates our client’s platform with Amazon’s storefront. Trying to understand how a development environment is setup through Amazon is a tricky task. It required hours of scouring Google for answers, contacting Amazon MWS support and hours of waiting. Hopefully this post can be a cheat sheet for developers trying to learn Amazon’s system.

**Step 1:**
Signup for a seller account on Amazon and select the **Professional** option. Go through the entire process and fill out you company name and address for your development account. You shouldn’t have to add a credit card or tax documentation even though it asks.

**Step 2:**
Login to your newly created account and open up a help ticket. Explain what you are developing and the reasons you need a **“staging account“**. Amazon should respond with instructions and the new account you created should be a development account. It should have all the normal features of a real Amazon account except that you can’t sell on the real Amazon.com, only in ungated categories on the staging version of Amazon. Also request the staging URL and credentials for testing orders at the same time.

**Step 3:**
After you’ve been informed by Amazon that Step 2 is complete, you can sign up with MWS as a developer. You should receive 5 things back:

Merchant ID
Marketplace ID
Developer Account #
AWS Access Key ID
Secret Key
You will then be able to send your client(s) to the same signup page with your developer ID. You application will then use #2,4,5 for every single client while only replacing #1 for each client’s requests.

**Step 4:**
Testing orders was one of the most unusual ways we have ever tested. It requires you to signin to: **https://mt.amazon.com** with the credentials you received in step 2. To test an order you must first list your products in your staging account. Then you must logout of your staging account, login to a real Amazon account and purchase items with a real account and credit card. For this reason Amazon suggests setting all pricing and shipping to $0.01.

Conclusion
Hopefully this helps save some time for many of you as it took our team hours to compile and learn all of the information above from Google and Amazon MWS support.

Comment: I have just contacted Amazon MWS and thay have stated:

At this time we do not offer staging accounts for our MWS service. MWS supports many different Amazon Services products. Each of these products has a different account structure and uses different sections of the MWS API. In order to validate the MWS submission the account needs to be attached to a valid seller account. These services have different functions for controlling availability of offers and listings, rules for order management, promotions available, as well as core functionality of the service itself.

Comment: @Stuart I got the exact same answer. Did you still find a way to use the staging environment?

Comment: So are you guys still using a normal account for testing? - I currently am but it's costing me £30 per month for the privilege, despite never actually selling anything/making any money from it... I'd love a free sandbox account that I can test with. @Jiam30

Comment: @Rick - Is it still the case that you have to pay Amazon just to develop, even though you will not be selling anything?

Comment: @kaiyaq sorry I'm not sure - I've since abandoned my Amazon dev. I'd be interested to know if you find out though

Comment: @Rick I spoke to Amazon's Seller Support and they confirmed that you need an active professional seller account for any kind of development using MWS. So yes, you have to pay Amazon as a developer even though you will not be selling.

Comment: @kaiyaq - are the charges different to use Amazon seller central as developer or actual seller? I cannot find anything regard the charge difference, I'm working on Amazon Selling partner API and need account to use

Comment: @coder771 you need an Amazon Professional selling account to develop whether you want to sell or not, that's up to you. The same account is used to selling and developing.

Answer (score 6):

You can get all inforamtion related to Amazon Sandbox account [From Here](https://payments.amazon.com/sdui/sdui/helpTab/Checkout-by-Amazon/Using-the-Checkout-by-Amazon-Sandbox/Overview-of-the-Sandbox)

CreditCard is for verification only that you are not some milicious user.